# subview of layer backed nsview clipped

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nsview

I have a subview of an layer backed nsview (set through storyboard) which exceed the bounds. For some reason it is getting clipped. Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Any luck finding out why?

Answer (score 1):

By default `NSView` will clip its subviews to its bounds.

If you have a **layer backed `NSView`**, `alignmentRectInsets:` might provide your solution. It returns an `NSEdgeInsets` that adds a margin to the layer's clipping bounds. Override the read-only property in your subview and return the desired insets.

If you need a more sophisticated way to inset the clipping, take a look at `alignmentRectForFrame:` and `frameForAlignmentRect:`.

See: [developer.apple.com/…/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSView/alignmentRectInsets)

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem.
It wasted me some time although the method is very simple.

There are two things need to pay attention to.

**First of all (THE MOST IMPORTANT!!)**,you should set your winow's contentview.wantsLayer YES;

**And then** , set the parent view's layer.maskesToBounds NO;

**What I did:**

```
self.window.contentView.wantsLayer = YES;
 self.testview.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor].CGColor;
 self.testview.layer.borderWidth = 3;
 self.testview.layer.borderColor = [NSColor blueColor].CGColor;
 self.testview.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
 NSView *aView = [[NSView alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(-50, -20, 100, 100)];
 aView.wantsLayer = YES;
 aView.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor].CGColor;
 [self.testview addSubview:aView];
```

**The effect**

[image]

GOOD LUCK